# Jenkins buildInfo object not receiving artifact

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I've been trying to use the Jenkins Artifactory plug-in to upload an artifact to Artifactory but I've been running into an issue with creating the artifact (what's odd is that my pipeline ends, so I must be triggering a silent error).

Here is the code (I give more details regarding what I think is going wrong below):

```
def server = Artifactory.server 'rc-artifact'

def uploadSpec =
    """{
        "files": [
            {
                "pattern": "${unencryptedZipName}",
                "target": "builds/SedTuningGui/${env.BUILD_NUMBER}/${unencryptedZipName}",
                "props": "type=zip"
             }
         ]
     }"""

def buildInfo = server.upload spec: unencryptedUploadSpec
print buildInfo.getProperties().toString()
```

and the console output (the portion of it that I'm comfortable showing):

```
[..., deployableArtifacts:[], artifacts:[], ...]
```

As you can see, both the 'artifacts' and 'deployable artifacts' arrays are empty, which means that the server didn't receive the zip file that I built.. I know that the zip file exists, because I've successfully robocopied it.

All of this has led me to believe that the *def buildInfo = server.upload...* line isn't working because the built zip file exists, but isn't included in the buildInfo object.

This is my first time working with a Jenkins pipeline, and I think I'm close to closing this issue out, I just need a bit of direction.

Comment: Do you see the build-info in the Artifactory UI? Also, do you see deployed file in the UI?

Answer (score 2):

The file spec you defined is `uploadSpec`, but in the following line `def buildInfo = server.upload spec: unencryptedUploadSpec` you use `unencryptedUploadSpec`. Try with 
 `def buildInfo = server.upload spec: uploadSpec`